# Add column of .75 quantile based off groupby

Tags: pandas, rounding, quantile, pandas-groupby

I have df with index as date and also column called scores. Now I want to maintain the df as it is but add column which gives the 0.7 quantile of scores for that day. Method of quantile would need to be midpoint and also be rounded to nearest whole number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've outlined one approach you could take, below.

Note that to round a value to the nearest whole number you should use Python's built-in `round()` function. See `round()` in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) for details.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(748)

# initialize base example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":np.arange(10), 
                   "score":np.random.uniform(size=10)})

duplicate_dates = np.random.choice(df.index, 5)

df_dup = pd.DataFrame({"date":np.random.choice(df.index, 5), 
                       "score":np.random.uniform(size=5)})

# finish compiling example data
df = df.append(df_dup, ignore_index=True)

# calculate 0.7 quantile result with specified parameters
result = df.groupby("date").quantile(q=0.7, axis=0, interpolation='midpoint')

# print resulting dataframe
# contains one unique 0.7 quantile value per date
print(result)

"""
0.7      score
date          
0     0.585087
1     0.476404
2     0.426252
3     0.363376
4     0.165013
5     0.927199
6     0.575510
7     0.576636
8     0.831572
9     0.932183
"""

# to apply the resulting quantile information to 
# a new column in our original dataframe `df`
# we can apply a dictionary to our "date" column

# create dictionary
mapping = result.to_dict()["score"]

# apply to `df` to produce desired new column
df["quantile_0.7"] = [mapping[x] for x in df["date"]]

print(df)

"""
    date     score  quantile_0.7
0      0  0.920895      0.585087
1      1  0.476404      0.476404
2      2  0.380771      0.426252
3      3  0.363376      0.363376
4      4  0.165013      0.165013
5      5  0.927199      0.927199
6      6  0.340008      0.575510
7      7  0.695818      0.576636
8      8  0.831572      0.831572
9      9  0.932183      0.932183
10     7  0.457455      0.576636
11     6  0.650666      0.575510
12     6  0.500353      0.575510
13     0  0.249280      0.585087
14     2  0.471733      0.426252
"""
```